# How can I create a mock Web::Syndication::SyndicationFeed with the Rust for Windows API for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking, windows-rs

I have started out with the [Rust for Windows RSS reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/rust/rss-reader-rust-for-windows) example documented on Microsoft's website. It works as expected but is rather simplistic. I want to expand on this example, turn it into something useful, and create a sample project that includes unit testing.

My application code does work as expected. Since network issues are common errors, I structured main so that the external call to retrieve the feed is in one function and the code that parses the feed (if one is returned) is in another.

```rust
fn check_syndication(client: &SyndicationClient) -> Result<SyndicationFeed> {
    let uri = Uri::CreateUri(h!("https://rpilocator.com/feed"))?;
    client.RetrieveFeedAsync(&uri)?.get()
}

fn parse_syndication(syndication_feed: SyndicationFeed) -> Vec<String> {
    let feed_items: IVector<SyndicationItem> = syndication_feed.Items().unwrap();

    feed_items
        .into_iter()
        .map(|item| item.Title().unwrap().Text().unwrap().to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

The idea was to create a mock SyndicationFeed object and then pass that into my `parse_syndication()` function like so:

```rust
#[test]
fn verify_parse_syndication() {
   let mock_uri = Uri::CreateUri(h!("https://mock_url.com")).unwrap();
   let mock_feed = SyndicationFeed::CreateSyndicationFeed(
      &HSTRING::from("Mock Title"),
      &HSTRING::from("Mock Subtitle"),
      &mock_uri,
   ).unwrap();
   
   let output = parse_syndication(mock_feed);
   assert_eq!(output.len(), 1);
}
```

While this test does compile and create a empty `SyndicationFeed`, I haven't been able to figure out how to populate it so that `SyndicationFeed.Items` contains a mocked up list of items.

```rust
IVector<SyndicationItem>
```

[The full source code on GitHub](https://github.com/aven-arlington/rpi-stock-checker/blob/tests/src/application.rs)

The [SyndicationFeed documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Web/Syndication/struct.SyndicationFeed.html#method.Items) doesn't indicate that there is any type of `add()` or `insert()` functionality. The `CreateSyndicationFeed()` function doesn't seem to provide a way to initialize the `SyndicationFeed` with data. I haven't found and other example of creating one in my search of GitHub, SO, or Google in general. I also searched for factory patterns and the creation of other similar types of object in the API.

I did try a different approach where I created a mock RSS feed in a xml file. Then I created a URI object that pointed to the local resource and provided it as an input to the `RetrieveFeedAsync()` call. Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work either. There were multiple issues with mixing forward slashes from the URI syntax and backslashes from the pathbuf. Even a hard coded string with the local resource would fail to open the file. I eventually abandoned this approach.

Comment: This should be possible, in theory: Like COM, the Windows Runtime establishes contracts through interfaces. They are publicly documented and can be implemented by anyone, giving full agency over the behavior to implementers. You *could* implement `ISyndicationFeed` and have it do anything. I don't think `windows-rs` is ready for WinRT-type authoring yet. What you could try instead is [`Load`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Web/Syndication/struct.SyndicationFeed.html#method.Load)ing an RSS document into a `SyndicationFeed` instance.

Comment: Thank you. Those suggestions pointed me in a workable direction. I was able to generate a mock XmlDocument with a String and call LoadFromXml to get some expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As IInspectable suggested, I was able to generate a mock XmlDocument with a String and call `SyndicationFeed::LoadFromXml` to get the expected `SyndicationFeed` output that I can test against.

```rust
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use windows::Data::Xml::Dom::XmlLoadSettings;
    pub struct XmlDoc {
        mock_xml: XmlDocument,
    }

    impl Default for XmlDoc {
        fn default() -> Self {
            let xml = String::from(
                "\
                <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><rss version=\"2.0\">\
                    <channel>\
                        <title>Mock Channel Title</title>\
                        <link>https://mockchannellink.com</link>\
                        <description>Mock Channel Description</description>\
                        <lastbuilddate>Fri, 08 Dec 2023 01:00:00 GMT</lastbuilddate>\
                        <item>\
                            <title>Mock Item Title</title>\
                            <description>Mock Item Description.</description>\
                            <link>https://mockitemlink.com</link>\
                            <guid ispermalink=\"false\">846c1690-b4ad-479a-95e3-2ca5ed4dfdbd</guid>\
                            <pubdate>Fri, 08 Dec 2023 01:00:00 GMT</pubdate>\
                        </item>\
                    </channel>\
                </rss>\
                ",
            );

            let xml_opts = XmlLoadSettings::new().expect("Opts creation failed");
            xml_opts
                .SetValidateOnParse(true)
                .expect("Set validate option failed");

            let mock_xml: XmlDocument = XmlDocument::new().expect("New XmlDoc::new failed");
            match mock_xml.LoadXmlWithSettings(&HSTRING::from(xml), &xml_opts) {
                Ok(doc) => doc,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("LoadXml failed: {}", e.code());
                }
            };
            Self { mock_xml }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn verify_parse_syndication() {
        let xml_doc = XmlDoc::default().mock_xml;

        let mock_feed = SyndicationFeed::new().expect("New SyndicationFeed failed");
        mock_feed
            .LoadFromXml(&xml_doc)
            .expect("Load from xml failed");
        let output = parse_syndication(mock_feed);
        assert_eq!(output.len(), 1);
    }
}
```